# No default toolchain configured after installing rustup

Tags: rust, rustup

I installed Rust using [rustup](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/install.html), but when I try to enter a Rust command like `cargo` or `rustc` in my console, the following error appears:

```
error: no default toolchain configured
```

Is this a known issue?

Comment: What do you get when running `rustup toolchain list`?

Comment: @E_net4 I get : "no installed toolchains"

Comment: Well, you've answered your own question. Install a toolchain (preferably default). The strange part of this is that it wasn't installed by default.

Comment: Yeah, as you mentionne, rustup-init.exe isn't suppose to install a default toolchain ? I can't even uninstall with "rustup self uninstall" command, the same error appear...

Comment: Can you update your question with everything that you have tried so far?

Comment: I have @Darkaird's experience, and I agree "The strange part of this is that it wasn't installed by default" -- my installation configuration (before running) says: `default toolchain: stable (default)` and after running, the message says: `info: default toolchain set to 'stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc' 

  stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc installed - rustc 1.66.0 (69f9c33d7 2022-12-12)` weird...

Comment: In my case I was using Windows installer; when  changed the value of `RUSTUP_HOME` and `CARGO_HOME` to the `C:\` directory directly: `set "RUSTUP_HOME=C:\.rustup" & set "CARGO_HOME=C:\.cargo"` , I got this error. When I uninstalled and let the default values: `%USERPROFILE%\.cargo` and `%USERPROFILE%\.rustup`, I didn't get this error anymore. That's OK, I guess plenty of other directories are installed at `%USERPROFILE%`, like `.matplotlib`, `.gem`, `.ipynb` , `.ssh`

Answer (score 338, accepted):

If it seems that rustup did not successfully install and configure the stable toolchain, you can do it manually:

```
rustup install stable
rustup default stable
```

After testing, it seems like my incomplete installation may have been caused by a network error. You can also try to reinstall to solve the problem.

Comment: I had a network error while installing rust -- my wi-fi connection dropped -- and had this same error message. Running these commands fixed it.

Comment: I installed rustup using yay, and it didn't run these commands it seems!

Comment: If you installed using yay please try the git version, mine worked. @ShubhamSharma

Comment: For me `rustup default stable` did the install as well, no need to run two commands

Answer (score 8):

The problem is due to my connection and my proxy which didn't allow rustc, cargo, and others to be downloaded.

I thought that the all the executables were all-in-one but apparently not.

Comment: I am 99.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999% certain that no proxies are even involved in my setup, and I still get the same errors.

Comment: I didn't say that this is THE solution for the problem but it may be one.

Comment: I use cntlm to get past my company's proxy.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had multirust installed and the following worked for me:

```
multirust install stable
multirust default stable
```

Answer (score 4):

I installed rust with root, but my IDE doesn't run as root, so I installed rust without root, all worked well.

Comment: Thank you , so sorry for my poor english. @Kaki