# Rust behind proxy, "error: no default toolchain configured"

Tags: rust, rustup

I installed Rust at home with no issues. Behind a company proxy I couldn't run rustup-init, so I installed 1.18 stable with an installer.

On every Rust command (e.g. cargo). I get the notification "error: no default toolchain configured". The only related question I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303915/no-default-toolchain-configured-after-installing-rustup), but the answer isn't very helpful. Knowing it is a proxy issue is useful, but I can't find an answer how to configure the proxy so that this works.

Comment: I have the same issue behind the corporate network of my company. The proxy blocks all network actions that cargo wants to perform. I usually build using rustc. But that might not be an option for you. I sometimes also use a personal hotspot from my phone to get around it.

Comment: @NoelWidmer I found it was not related to the proxy at all. Although I still can't use cargo, at least the basic rust compiler works and cargo has different errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to why I'm getting this error message:

The Rust installer put two locations on my path:

- `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.cargo\bin`
- `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Rust\bin`

The first one seems to have dummy .exes (which for some reason are 4.62MB) and the second one contains cargo and rustc.

I don't know why these dummy .exes exist, but if I take them off the path I can compile simple Rust programs.

Comment: *I don't know why these dummy .exes exist* — that's how the actual version multiplexing works. Without them, you won't be able to install new toolchain versions with `rustup install another-version` or any of the other features.

Comment: Ok that does make some sense, but having them on the path before the actually installed version seems like making things complicated. There should be a hint what should be done next to the error, because Google isn't helpful right now.

Comment: *seems like making things complicated* — it's the **only** way for it to work. They *have* to be first so that they can intercept calls to `rustc` or `cargo` and then delegate the call to the correct version of the intended tool. To fix "error: no default toolchain configured", you need to configure a default toolchain. That's usually done with `rustup default stable` or whatever version is preferred.

Comment: @Shepmaster that's a bug then if you didn't use or have rustup, but instead used the installer (as I mentioned I couldn't get rustup to run with the proxy). So I think for non-rustup installs this is a bug.

Comment: Potentially... It appears you were able to install rustup itself (which is what added the shim executables) and then not able to install a toolchain. Do you have a `rustup` binary? That would be pretty solid proof.

Comment: @Shepmaster only the fake one. Maybe the rustup-init starts copying files before being able to download anything.

Comment: What "fake" one? There is only one `rustup` binary.

Comment: Nvm, everything else is fake in that folder, except the rustup executable.