# Rust installation fails on Linux with error: 'sysinfo failure'

Tags: rust, rustup

I have had rust working on a remote server some weeks ago but now all of a sudden when trying to install it I get the error: 'sysinfo failure' multiple times and then it gets stuck when trying to download/install rustc, when running the following:
`curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`

rustup seems to get installed since I can run rustup --version which returns:

`rustup 1.24.2 (755e2b07e 2021-05-12)`
`info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.`

However rustc --version returns:

`'rustc' is not installed for the toolchain 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'`

So it tells me to do run the command: rustup component add rustc
But this gives me the error: `Missing manifest in toolchain 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'`

For this error I found another post which says that rustup probably did not successfully install, which is the case, but I have tried reinstalling multiple times without any progress now. To my knowledge there has not even been any changes to the server so this really is strange. And when checking ls ~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/ there is only "components  rust-installer-version" so no manifest or config files...

I have also tried installing different versions of rustup such as 1.51.0 but the error 'sysinfo failure' keeps coming up with no more info. Does anyone what could be wrong or how I could troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No default toolchain configured after installing rustup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303915/no-default-toolchain-configured-after-installing-rustup)

Comment: Sadly not, I did what was suggested in that post but both return stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - (rustc does not exist). And then I am back in the loop explained in the post that when reinstalling I get the error 'sysinfo failure'